# how to react native images to server by use apollo-client

Tags: react-native, graphql, strapi

currently i use apollo-client in react-navie and strapi as the backend. i try to upload images which get by ImageCropPicker to server by use  apollo-client, but it always show "‘Upload’ scalar serialization unsupported." error . is there anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/yaacovCR/graphql-tools-fork/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

```
export const UploadScalar = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Upload',
  description: 'The `Upload` scalar type represents a file upload.',
  parseValue(value: any) {
    return value
  },
  serialize(value: any) {
    return value
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    throw new Error('‘Upload’ scalar literal unsupported.')
  },
})
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i still confused, these code is look like server part code, but i still don't know how to format my client file type to match server side Upload type